# Problem to store number with ifeqcase from xstring

Tags: grouping

I need the value of a variable, set in ifeqcase, outside of ifeqcase. For example this code doesn't work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calculator,calculus}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[fontsize=22pt]{scrextend}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans Quotation}
\geometry{papersize{30cm,19.35cm},left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\valeurcal}[2]{
\SUBTRACT{1}{\ra}{\partiell}
\MULTIPLY{\partiell}{#1}{\partielll}
\MULTIPLY{\ra}{#2}{\partiell}
\ADD{\partiell}{\partielll}{\leresultat}
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\ra=0.0+0.2}{1}{
\valeurcal{0}{5}
\ROUND[0]{\leresultat}{\coupe}
\IfEqCase{\coupe}{%
{1}{ \COPY{5}{\nouvcoupe}}% test with calculator
{2}{  \def\nouvcoupe{6}}}% test with def, edef and gdef (thank for the answer)
value of nouvcoupe : \nouvcoupe}
\end{document}
```

give me : Undefined control sequence. (compiled with xelatex)

The probleme seems to come with `\valeurcal{0}{5}`. If I replace `\valeurcal{0}{5}` by `\COPY{2}{\leresultat}` I can compile it  (but it don't do the job)!

`\valeurcal{0}{5}` calculate `0*(1-\ra)+5*\ra` where `\ra` 
What do you advise to me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\gdef\nouvcoupe{6}
```

*g*lobal *def*inition

Comment: Thank for your answer. I've made some more tests and edited my question to encircle the problem.

Comment: give _complete_  test examples and not only fragments ....

Answer (score 0):

OK `[\def\nouvcoupe{6}]` was missing

```
\IfEqCase{\coupe}{%
{1}{ \COPY{5}{\nouvcoupe}}% test with calculator
{2}{  \def\nouvcoupe{6}}}[\def\nouvcoupe{6}]
```

is oK

Comment: What about if I need to use multiple conditions/variables for the same case, for example CASE1: if a=1 and /orb=2 : then do this and so on.Identifying multiple variables in the same case